# Site with absurdly powerful characters for D&D 3/3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, product-identification, online-resources, character-templates

A good ten years ago a friend of mine told me about a site somewhere where absurdly powerful characters for D&D 3/3.5 were listed, with detailed level-by-level character progression.

As far as I can remember, it included characters like a mage who turns into a beholder with a beholder's full powers and a four-armed humanoid that hits for over a hundred damages with a regular spear.
And all of it perfectly legal: they just combined every handbook's feats and spell with each other to exploit all advantages and synergies.

I've never been interested in powergaming so after a cursory glance I dismissed that site: but now I'd wish to find it again to show another friend and who'd wish to take a look himself.

Do you know what site it could be?

Comment: Hi Zab, unfortunately recommendations requests like this are off-topic for our site. However you might have better luck asking on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) or in our [chat].

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check and assumed it was ok. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm under the impression that recommendation requests are about "what game can I use?", not "where can I find this information?". While in this case it might be very difficult to find a specific site that only details broken builds like the beholder mage, the übercharger (and I'd guess the omniscifier and Pun-Pun at least), this question should be ok. At least we could name some possible places where to find those builds, and a word of caution on the difference between theoretical optimization and actual "perfectly legal" builds which are really explitig bugs and vague wording. To the meta!

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: [Is this question about a site listing absurdly powerful D&D 3e/3.5e characters really a recommendation question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11160)

Comment: Are you looking for any site or collection, or a specific one?

Comment: NautArch, I was looking for a specific site but, failing that, any will do.

Comment: This question, after all, seems like a recommendation question as the intention is to have a source for popular optimised builds instead of looking for that one product that the person was looking for - they are fine with any optimisation site. So after Voting re-open and leave open, I'm now voting to close. The answer helped out but really the question was off-topic, and not suited to the stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many sites list “extremely powerful” builds, often with few if any entries that actually reach well into the limits of D&D 3.5e’s potential. Ultimately, there is a build that can have every stat as high as they choose to make it, and every ability in the game they choose to have, at 1st level—that would be Pun-Pun, and nothing is ever going to beat that for anything. Pun-Pun can have Epic Spellcasting<sup>1</sup> and arbitrarily-high Spellcraft, so they can instantly create and cast an epic spell to do near-literally anything at all. Pun-Pun can also be an actual deity, and have any salient divine abilities they might wish—like alter reality.

To list *anything else* requires some kind of limitation that prevents Pun-Pun, because otherwise there’s no point in having anything on the list other than Pun-Pun. The traditional “theoretical optimization” limitation is “no infinite or arbitrary loops,” such as Pun-Pun uses to push all their stats into the stratosphere. This is, for example, the limitation put on the “Finite Values” section of the [World Records Listing](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=11680) (which frustratingly lacks links to the majority of record-holders).

I have spent some time trying to find a version of the World Records with links, and cannot. I’m pretty sure there was, once, but so much has been lost to time. However, [this Giantitp.com list of famous optimization builds](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?258580-Famous-optimized-character-builds) looks to be fairly complete, and actually has links for a lot of stuff, huzzah! And [minmaxforum’s Handbook Index](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=399.0) is a must-see here—it’s got reasonably-practical guides for most classes, and a few theoretical optimization resources as well.

1. <sub>Yes, an epic feat at 1st level. Dragons, man.</sub>

Comment: Do any of the sites you list contain the builds OP remembers? Or is this more of "I'm not sure what you're talking about exactly, but here are some places with builds"

Comment: @NautArch Abusing beholder mage is a pretty common trick, and several entries here **definitely** do that. I’m not personally familiar with any TO build that features a four-armed character with a spear (and would be shocked if that’s actually the best one can do, since one can get vastly more arms than that—see the various X of Smack builds), but I also haven’t gone through all of those links.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'm unsure they're the one I'm looking for (I haven't found either build I remembered over there but there's also a few dead links among the ones listed so maybe it's one of those): anyhow, they're impressive works of optimization and will do fine.